# 回答が寄せられた後に質問を削除し、少し内容を変えて再投稿するのはあり？

Tags: 討議, 質問の仕方

お世話になっております。
あるユーザの質問に回答したのですが、
先ほど見ると、その質問が削除され同様の質問が条件を付与して別の質問として投稿されました。
前回の回答で解決しなかったのか分かりませんが、
回答がついた質問を削除し、別に質問として立ち上げるのはアリなのでしょうか？
新しく投稿された質問を閲覧はしたのですが、「また削除されるのでは？」と回答に消極的になります。

一体、どういう対応をするのがベストなのでしょうか？
変な質問ですが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「質問の削除について」では内容が掴めないと思ったので、タイトルを変更してみました。

Comment: なしでしょうー！マイナス票投じて前の質問のURL貼ってみては。

Comment: @YOSUKE ありがとうございます。削除されているのでページ自体存在しない状態です。私としても質問文を編集する形で直して欲しいのですが……

Comment: 履歴でURL残ってもないんですか、、そうですか。。

Comment: でも、解答がついてるのに、質問内容がしれっと変わってて、解答がズレてしまうってのもイヤですよね。。。

Comment: なるほど、そういう考え方もありますね。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

質問側に気づいてもらって

「質問内容を変更したいので本件は
　→クローズして別の質問を立ち上げます」
　→一部変更しました」

と、いったんブレイクすることを宣言してもらうのがいいんですけれどね。
削除してしまうのは回答側に対してちょっと礼を欠くことだとは思いますし、「また削除されるのでは？」と思ってしまうのも同意できます。

ただしシステムのルールとして「回答やコメントのついた質問は削除できなくなる」までやるべきか、、と言われると、「そこまでする必要はないかもしれない」と個人的には思います。

Comment: そうですね。クローズなら閉じた後もみれるので何かしらコメントを残してもらえたり反応があれば"そういうことなんだな"と思いますし、別の解答を投稿しようとも思いますが・・・ただ、今回で2度目なので(1回目も2回目も同じ人)ちょっと回答する気はもう起きないですね……。どちらにしろ、唐突に削除よりもコメントおいてからクローズの方が回答者への配慮になって良いと思います。（回答者側の対応と言うよりは質問者側の対応だと思いますが……）。ちなみに私はクローズがあれば削除機能自体いらないと思ってます。(削除機能に猛烈に反対というわけではなく……)。

Comment: システム上は回答にプラス投票されていたり、複数の回答が付いている場合には質問を自己削除することはできないようになっていますね。 http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions

Comment: そうなんですね。1件のみの場合……削除の猶予が残されてるのは何故なんでしょうね

Comment: それなりに時間をかけて丁寧に回答しているのに、削除は失礼ですね。少なくとも行動履歴に記録を残せませんかね。次回同じ人にうっかり回答しないようにします。

Comment: 削除された質問であっても自分の行動履歴には残して欲しいですね。コメントに手がかりになりそうなことを書いたら一時間もしないうちに質問が削除されてしまいちょっと萎えた:-( もう誰の質問にコメントしたのか憶えてない。。。