# 回答やコメントがついているが、トータルでマイナス票されているので、削除したい質問がある

Tags: 討議

[x forwarding した firefox@ubuntu14.04 で日本語入力ができない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/22850/754) の質問をしたところ、１件の回答がついたのちに、マイナス票がつきました。いただいた回答には、今の所 + の投票も - の投票も入っていない状態です。ので、システム的にはこの質問自体を削除できるはずです。

似た質問 ([vagrant の中で起動した firefox を x forwarding してみたら文字化けている](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/22313/754)) をしたことがあるのですが、そのときもあまり質問自体の票は、最後まで伸びなかったので、今回も、試行錯誤して編集して、答えに辿りついたとしても、最悪、最後までマイナス票が入ったままになることもありうると思っています。

現行のシステム上、２つ以上回答が付与された場合には、基本的には質問の削除はできなくなると理解しています。また、試行錯誤の過程で、さらに投票結果がマイナス方向に振れないとも限りません。で、あるならば、システム上可能となっているし、いっその事質問自体を、今の時点で削除してしまった方がいいのでは、とも考えられます。

質問:

- トータルで票がマイナスになってしまってしまっている質問を、削除できるからしてしまうのは、やはりなしですか。

関連:

[回答が寄せられた後に質問を削除し、少し内容を変えて再投稿するのはあり？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2094/754) : このメタでの総意としては、勝手に削除してしまうのはなし、ということになったかと思いますが、「質問に対するマイナス票」という観点がすっぽりない気がしたので、改めてこの質問をしています。(議論の結果、このメタと同じ結論になるかもしれませんが。。)

Comment: 良い質問だったと思う（後から見た人の役にたつ）のですが、日本語版はプログラミングとシステム管理が分かれていないので、こういうことが起きる気がします。

Comment: 関連で質問した者ですが、私はコメントなり、次の質問なりで一言あるだけで納得できます。せっかく考えた回答を消した理由が分からなかったため悶々としちゃってました。。。。質問覗いてみたけどクローズするような内容だとは思えないんだけどトピックから外れていると言う理由でクローズ票入ってますね……質問タイトルから単なるソフトの使用方法だと判断したのかしら？

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi 分かれていないので、何がオントピックかは、コミュニティーが決める、ひとまずは http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic で仮決めされている、という認識ですね。

Comment: @Myaku クローズ票自体は、別に問題ないと思っています。それによって、オントピックかどうかについてのレビューが発生し、多数決的にオントピックかオフトピックかが決まるので。 (最近だと帰納法がいい例かと) ただ、マイナス投票は、信用度に反映されます。いきなりマイナスが入って、かつ、このさきも upvote が入らなさそうならば、信用度に対して最適化した場合には、この質問はそもそもしなかった方がよかったということになり、だったら削除できるときに削除したくなる構造がある、ということが議論したいことですね。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

誰かが upvote してくれてトータル0になったので、ひとまず議題の質問は、削除せずにそのまま調査・編集を続行します。