# 質問の第一声に「お世話になっています」は不要な気がします

Tags: 討議

[回答が寄せられた後に質問を削除し、少し内容を変えて再投稿するのはあり？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2094/5505)

この質問の第一声が「お世話になっております」となっています
個人的にはQAサイトにおいて質問者と回答者はフェアな力関係が好ましいのではないかと考えており
下手にへりくだった言葉遣いはしなくてもよいのではないでしょうか？

もちろん多くの質問者さんは大きくへりくだった言葉遣いをせず素直で対等なスタンスで質問をなさっているかたもいらっしゃいます
だからこそ大きくへりくだった言葉遣いはコミュニティの一員としてのスタンスの違いからか違和感を感じるんです
みなさんはへりくだった言葉遣いについて賛成ですか？　反対ですか？

**補足**
挨拶が必要かという質問とは別物として、「へりくだった」姿勢の質問が適切かという質問とお考えください

Comment: 日本の文化だからしょうがないですね。本家で挨拶から始めたら、まず編集で削除されます。

Comment: 挨拶や署名は本家でも議論になってますね： http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/286934 [冒頭のあいさつは自動で取り除くようにした](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/286934)という話も。/・・・と書きましたが、挨拶全般の話や挨拶に限った話ではなく、へりくだった言葉遣いについての意見でしょうか。

Comment: @unarist  「挨拶全般の話や挨拶に限った話ではなく、へりくだった言葉遣いについての意見でしょうか」←話が膨らみそうなので今回は「へりくだった」挨拶全般ということで質問させてください

Answer (score 5):

個人(質問者)の自由の範疇だとは思いますが、個人的には不要だと思います。

Answer (score 4):

> 下手にへりくだった言葉遣いはしなくてもよいのではないでしょうか？

へりくだる必要はないと思います。が、挨拶が書かれていようが、へりくだっていようが、回答はなんら変わらないので、個人的にはどっちでもいいです。

コメントで指摘したり、編集で除去するかどうかは、個々の判断でご自由にというところでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

反対ですかね。

> 下手にへりくだった言葉遣いはしなくてもよいのではないでしょうか？

そうですね。最初に`こんにちは`や`お世話になっています`は必要ないと思います。理由はユーザーには階級みたいなのが存在していないからです(信用度などは別)。
ただ、礼儀正しくしたほうが良いというのが賛成派の意見なのかなと思います。